# How to test Google Pay flow on android app with googles test card suite

Tags: android, google-pay

Currently I am trying to use a test creditcard from Googles [Test Card Suite](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite) in the native Google Pay App.

Currently all I get is a native gpay popup, which shows a "add a payment method", after clicking the google pay button. On Web on the other hand I see multiple test creditcards after clicking on the Pay with Google button with the same account.
The calling app is set up with the test flag

```
        val walletOptions = Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder()
                .setEnvironment(WalletOptions.ENVIRONMENT_TEST)
                .build()
```

Am I not able to use those card with the native gpay app?

Comment: There's an issue preventing the test cards from appearing in the native integrations.

Comment: @Soc, thank you very much for your response. Do you mean a general problem or is this a temporary situation and/or maybe publicly communicated?

Comment: It's a temporary problem that requires a fix. I don't have an ETA unfortunately.

Comment: I have same problem. It shows my personal bank cards instead test cards from suite.

Comment: I was able to use my live creditcards on TEST without getting charged. Maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

The Google Pay API now supports [test cards from your PSPs](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/resources/test-card-suite#gateway-test-cards). Add configuration for your payment gateway under the `tokenizationSpecification` parameter, when you use Google Pay in `TEST` mode and you'll be able to complete successful and filed payment flows.